# Union of subsets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1,...,A_n$ $n$ subset of  $\mathbb{R}$. Show that:
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(A_k\setminus A_{k+1}\right)\cup\left(
A_n\setminus A_1\right)\cup\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A_k\right)$$

We can easily show that $$\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(A_k\setminus A_{k+1}\right)\cup\left(
A_n\setminus A_1\right)\cup\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A_k\right)\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k$$

For the other inclusion, i began my solution like this, let $x\in \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k$. we have two cases:

the first case: $x\in\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A_k$ in this case we acheive the result.

the second case: $x\notin\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A_k$
here we have $x\in \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k$ and $x\notin\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}A_k$  but how can we find a $k\in\left\{1,...,n\right\}$ such that:

$x\in A_k$ and $x\notin A_{k+1}$ with $A_{n+1}=A_1$.

Comment: Your statement that you can find a $k$ should be made more explicitly. You know there is $i,j$ such that $x\in A_{i}$ and $x\not\in A_j.$ From there, deduce the existence of $k.$

Comment: What is $A_{n+1}$? You only fixed $A_1,\ldots, A_n$.

Comment: @AlvinL in this case, $A_{n+1}=A_1$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews intuitively it's clear, but my aim here is how the write this on the right way.

Comment: Uhh, some kind of symmetric difference inspired thingamajing? I'm feeling induction. Might get messy.

Comment: Alvin yes exactly, there is no easy way with the induction

Answer (score 1):

A more rigorous approach to proving $k$ exists would go something like this.

> **Lemma:** Let $B\subsetneq \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ be non-empty. Then there exists a $k$ such that $k\in B$ and $k+1\notin B,$ (where $k+1$ is suitably defined for $k=n.$)

In your case $B=\{i\mid x\in A_i\}.$

**Proof:** Let $i$ be the largest element of $B$ and $j$ be the smallest element not in $B.$

If $i\neq n$ we can choose $k=i.$

If $j\neq 1,$ we can choose $k=j-1.$

If $i=n, j=1,$ we can choose $k=n.$

Comment: yes, Clearly this subset B has a greatest element $k$. and this k are the solution if $k$ is smaller than n-1

Comment: @david well, if $n\in B$ is the largest element, you can't deduce $1\notin B.$

Comment: @david okay, updated to use the lemma approach and them added a proof for that. Much easier than my original approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your time,

So i suppose that i find a solution, so here is my solution:

since $x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i$, then we have two cases:

First case : if $x\in A_1$. we consider the subset: $$E=\{ i\in\{1,...,n\}~\mid~ \forall j\in\{1,...,i\},~x\in A_j\}$$
Clearly $E\neq\emptyset$ since $1\in E$, then $E$ has the largest element $k$,

if $k=n$ n, then $x\in\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i$. Contradiction

then $1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1$.

then we have $x\in A_k$ and $x\notin A_{k+1}$.

second case :if $x\notin A_1$
we consider the subset: $$E=\{ i\in\{1,...,n\}~\mid~x\in A_i\}$$
Clearly $E\neq\emptyset$, then $E$ has a largest element $k$.
if $1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1$, we acheive the result.

if $k=n$, then $x\in A_n\setminus A_1$.